# (wrong-type-argument stringp nil) [36 times] when loading emacs, even with init.el commented out

Tags: config

*I'm definitely loading the correct file. There's no rogue* `~/.emacs` *or byte compiled file*.

When I load emacs, even with my entire init.el commented out, the first line in `*messages*`, the first line is messages is `(wrong-type-argument stringp nil) [36 times]`.

If I run emacs with my init.el totally commented out, and `--debug-init`, I don't get backtraces for these errors.

If I invoke emacs with `-q`, I don't get these errors at all in `*messages*`.

I'm not sure how to proceed in debugging this, but there are more normal problems too, so I can't just ignore. For example, zenburn won't load - it too fails with `(wrong-type-argument stringp nil)`, but I can get a backtrace for this, and it's related caused by `file-name-directory` receiving nil.

If I 'manually' load my commented-out init file, by running `emacs -q -l init.el` there are no complaints about `(wrong-type-argument stringp nil) [36 times]`
What could be causing these initial, non `debug-on-init`able stringp errors, and how can I fix them?

- EDIT - New information. Deleting every `.elc` in elpa seems to fix this problem, and recompiling the `.elc` files re-introduces it.

Comment: Perhaps you compiled your init.el file and that's (init.elc) what is getting loaded?

Comment: Can you first ensure that the init.el you are debugging is actually being read by emacs? Put a line like `(message "Beginning of init")` at the very beginning of that file and something like `(message "End of init")` at its end. If your init is causing those errors, they should come between those 2 messages. Make sure that you don't have a `~/.emacs` lying around because emacs will pick that up instead if available.

Comment: If the messages do get printed and the errors happen before the `Beginning of init` display in \*Messages\*, then you need to start looking into the presence of `.dir-locals.el` and such.

Comment: Based on your latest update about .elc files, then try narrowing down to the package whose .elc caused this problem. For simplicity, rename the `elpa/` dir to something like `elpa.bkp/` and then move dirs (already containing the elc files) using binary approach (first move half of the package dirs, restart emacs, if things are good, move half from the remaining, repeat) from `elpa.bkp/` to `elpa/`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're not loading the init file you think you're loading.

Double check if the `init.el` file you use with `-q` and `--debug-init` is the same file you use when loading emacs *normally*. Check for the first line in `*Messages*` starting with `Loading <path-to-init-file>...`

Comment: This looks like a comment rather than an answer

Comment: It's definitely the same file

Comment: No, this looks like an answer, *not* a comment, to me. It might not be an ideal  or complete answer, but it is an answer, and a good one. The OP explicitly asked about "*how to proceed in debugging this*". This answer is a start.

Comment: @AndrewSwann, indeed I wanted to provide a comment originally. But I don't have enough reputation to do so yet.